# Managing multiple Java Applications

Tags: spring, spring-security, jms, rabbitmq

Right now we are looking into developing a live video chat applications that will consist of a video (wowza), web (spring mvc), chat(rabbitmq)... parts.  I would like to divide each part into seperate application.

Whats the best way to have these applications communicate.  I read about Rabbitmq as the messaging system, is a popular way to scale and connect applications.  IS this something that the community regularly uses?

Also each application will need authentication, we would like to use Spring security for this, whats the best way to have all the different applications use one security point.  Is Rabbitmq good for this, or stick with jms

I have been out of the Java world for a while, im a bit outdated, please help me with this.

Comment: Tough decisions ahead !
I don't know much about Wowza, but are you intending to stream/transmit video across this common messaging bus ? Setting the security bit aside for the moment, what do you need this messaging layer to do ? Also, will you be 100% java, or will you have non-java participants sending/receiving as well ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we are hoping to only use java, but we may end up using some c++ for video rendering.  so we want to be prepared for it.  So to answer your question, we need to be ready for other languages as well.  Also the messaging bus, example: user starts a video chat (1 app) at the same time chats (2nd app) and as they are talking to each other they want to publish their conversation to public (3rd app picks up the video conversation and transcodes it) All 3 applications need to be communicating with each other at that time plus share user/login info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you expect to implement using multiple languages, RabbitMQ sounds like a better choice since it is an AMQP implementation which alleges to support a more diverse language set. I mean, most JMS implementations have fairly rich language support (aside from Java) but it seems AMQP has more momentum in this area.

You might also consider [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/). Based on your description, it seems you might not need as much on the backend (queueing, persistence etc.). You may also find it easier to implement your messaging in transport protocols that are simpler to manage for a distributed user community that might be stuck behind firewalls, need to use proxy servers etc.

//Nicholas

Comment: one more question, what if we stick to the Java stack, what options are there, is jms a better solution? is there anything else?